# How to add new column in dataframe based on the other dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have 2 dataframes but both are not same. I have to update one based on the 2nd.

Example:
df1:

```
Region  Sub_Region  Run_Date    Status   Reason
ASPAC   CRM         2022-01-11  Success
ASPAC   Genesys     2022-01-11  Failed
LATAM   CRM         2022-01-11  Success
```

df2:

```
Region   Sub_Region   Max_Load_Date
NA       CRM          2021-08-12
ASPAC    CRM          2021-03-15
LATAM    CRM          2021-10-11
NA       Genesys      2021-12-18
ASPAC    Genesys      2021-11-18
LATAM    Genesys      2021-04-16
```

In Final Output:

```
Region  Sub_Region  Run_Date    Status   Reason  Max_Load_Date
ASPAC   CRM         2022-01-11  Success          2021-03-15
ASPAC   Genesys     2022-01-11  Failed
LATAM   CRM         2022-01-11  Success          2021-10-11
```

The df1 will update when the status = 'Success'

Comment: Hi, what were your attempts and where did they fail at (if at all)? As it stands, you're making other people do all the job, which is kind of rude, right?

Comment: Output for 'ASPAC   Genesys ' ''Max_Load_Date' seems wrong, should be '2021-11-18'

Comment: @Corralien:  Ok I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter out your dataframe after `merge`:

```
df1['Max_Load_Date'] = df1.merge(df2, on=['Region', 'Sub_Region'], how='left') \
                          .query("Status == 'Success'")['Max_Load_Date']
print(df)

# Output
  Region Sub_Region    Run_Date   Status  Reason Max_Load_Date
0  ASPAC        CRM  2022-01-11  Success     NaN    2021-03-15
1  ASPAC    Genesys  2022-01-11   Failed     NaN           NaN
2  LATAM        CRM  2022-01-11  Success     NaN    2021-10-11
```

Comment: @hpchavaz. You are right. All my apologies!

Comment: Getting error - ValueError: 'Region' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.

Comment: Update your post with the output of `df1.info()` and `df2.info()`, please.